# Asp.net how to correct the error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 public partial class Bookcheck : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter ();
        SqlConnection cnn=new SqlConnection();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string constr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        if (IsValid != null)
        {
            constr = @"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =librarymanagement; 
 Integrated Security=SSPI";
            cnn.ConnectionString = constr;
            try
            {
                if (cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    cnn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string str1 = null;
                str1 = ex.ToString();
            }
            cmd.Connection = cnn ;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText  = "spbookcheck";
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bookid", txtid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nameofthebook", txtnb.Text);
            da.SelectCommand=cmd;
            try
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string strErrMsg = ex.Message;
                // throw new ApplicationException
            }
            finally
            {
                da.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
                cnn.Dispose();
            }
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Msg.Text = "bookcheck successfully";
                Response.Redirect("Issueofbook.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Msg.Text="bookcheck failed";
            }
        }



    }

 }
```

My error

> Index out of range exception the unhandle by the user cannot find
>   table 0

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: @joel Etherton The record are not insert and then the error is out of range exception throw in user

Comment: @joel Etherton the page are run and then any reacord insert pls help me how do i change....

Comment: @kannan: The code is dependent on a stored procedure that you didn't include. You're also mentioning that the record didn't insert when you're using a Select command.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

is assuming that there are tables in your data set. Need to check that `ds.Tables.Count` is > 0 before trying to access a table.